# Share folder between two ubuntu machines, one of them doesn't have internet connection

Tags: shared-folders

I wondered if i could share folders between two ubuntu machines, even if one of them doesn't have Internet connection.

In fact, i searched all day long for a way to do that, but all i found is that i should install SAMBA or openssh, but i actually can't cause as i said, i don't have Internet on one of the two PCs.

First i tried to find a way to share the Internet connection, but i was told that it wasn't possible while i didn't have two network cards in the PC that was connected to the Internet.

I would be grateful if someone could give me an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest installing `openssh-server` on the machine *with* the internet connection, then using the command `scp remote-user@remote-host:/path/to/file ~/place/to/store` to copy a file from remote to local on the internet-less machine, as ssh client is pre-installed by default (if I remember correctly).

Alternatively, with openssh-server installed, on the desktop of the internet-less machine go to file->connect to server and change the type to ssh. Then enter a username, password & host to connect to the remote machine and mount the filesystem locally.

There's also [this relevant xkcd](http://xkcd.com/949/).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers. It works very well.

Answer (score 1):

You can download (on the PC that has internet) the deb packages necessary to install Samba, then transfer them, using a usb pen, or something similar, to the PC that has no internet.

(Be carefull, you need to transfer the dependence packages,if any, to the internet-less PC, too)

Doing a little research on the dependencies,what I get from `rpm -qpR samba-3.6.5-86.fc17.1.x86_64.rpm` is:

```
config(samba) = 2:3.6.5-86.fc17.1
libacl.so.1()(64bit)  
libacl.so.1(ACL_1.0)(64bit)  
libattr.so.1()(64bit)  
libattr.so.1(ATTR_1.0)(64bit)  
libc.so.6()(64bit)  
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.10)(64bit)  
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.14)(64bit)  
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.15)(64bit)  
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit)  
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.3)(64bit)  
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.3.2)(64bit)  
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.3.4)(64bit)  
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.4)(64bit)  
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.5)(64bit)  
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.6)(64bit)  
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.8)(64bit)  
libcap.so.2()(64bit)  
libcom_err.so.2()(64bit)  
libcrypt.so.1()(64bit)  
libcups.so.2()(64bit)  
libdl.so.2()(64bit)  
libdl.so.2(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit)  
libgssapi_krb5.so.2()(64bit)  
libgssapi_krb5.so.2(gssapi_krb5_2_MIT)(64bit)  
libk5crypto.so.3()(64bit)  
libk5crypto.so.3(k5crypto_3_MIT)(64bit)  
libkrb5.so.3()(64bit)  
libkrb5.so.3(krb5_3_MIT)(64bit)  
liblber-2.4.so.2()(64bit)  
libldap-2.4.so.2()(64bit)  
libnsl.so.1()(64bit)  
libnsl.so.1(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit)  
libpam.so.0()(64bit)  
libpam.so.0(LIBPAM_1.0)(64bit)  
libpopt.so.0()(64bit)  
libpopt.so.0(LIBPOPT_0)(64bit)  
libresolv.so.2()(64bit)  
libresolv.so.2(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit)  
librt.so.1()(64bit)  
librt.so.1(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit)  
libtalloc.so.2()(64bit)  
libtalloc.so.2(TALLOC_2.0.2)(64bit)  
libtdb.so.1()(64bit)  
libtdb.so.1(TDB_1.2.1)(64bit)  
libtdb.so.1(TDB_1.2.2)(64bit)  
libtdb.so.1(TDB_1.2.5)(64bit)  
libwbclient.so.0()(64bit)  
libz.so.1()(64bit)  
logrotate >= 0:3.4
pam >= 0:0.64
rpmlib(CompressedFileNames) <= 3.0.4-1
rpmlib(FileDigests) <= 4.6.0-1
rpmlib(PayloadFilesHavePrefix) <= 4.0-1
rtld(GNU_HASH)  
samba-common = 2:3.6.5-86.fc17.1
systemd-sysv  
systemd-units  
systemd-units  
systemd-units  
rpmlib(PayloadIsXz) <= 5.2-1
```

Now you just have to grab one by one and install the debs on the internet-less PC.
Good luck! :)

Comment: yeah, I've tried, but it is really not simple. ( because of dependency problems )

Comment: I'll need more information to help. Your dependence problem is: You cannot install SAMBA although you put the dependencies on the same folder as the Samba deb?
If this is the case, you have to install the dependencies debs first; to make sure everything goes fine. Download them too to a usb pen.

Comment: Thank you, if jackweirdy's method didn't work, i would've been obliged to try this one.